# Equation with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can i do this equation with library Matplotlib?

*f(x) = exp(sqrt(x))/2 - sqrt(x**3)/5 + 2*

```
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np
import math

fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)

ax1.plot(x, 0.5.np.exp)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you know how to write mathematical notation in python in general?

Comment: if _x_ spans from -3 to +3, then your function implies taking the square root of a negative number… while this is perfectly possible if we introduce complex numbers, is dealing with complex numbers what do you want to do?

Answer (score -1):

This represents your equation, but please double check it.

```
import math
e1 = lambda x: 0.5 * math.exp(-1 * math.sqrt(x)) - (0.2 * math.sqrt(x^3)) + 2

e1(1) # 1.901097008111102
```